# Clicking on the next button - unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, click

I am using selenium to go to a url and click search. This part works fine. After searching, I want to scrape all the href URL's associated with the athletes on the page and click on the next page. I have tried several class and xpath locations without success...

Goal:

```
1) Go to the URL listed
2) Click search buttton
3) Scrape all the urls that go to each athletes profile page
4) Click the next page button at the bottom
5) Repeat this process through all the pages
```

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

TIMEOUT = 5

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(TIMEOUT)

url = 'https://n.rivals.com/search#?formValues=%7B%22sport%22:%22Football%22,%22recruit_year%22:2021,%22offer_and_visit_type%22:%5B%22Offer%22%5D,%22prospect_profiles.prospect_colleges.offer%22:true,%22page_number%22:1,%22page_size%22:50%7D'

try:
    driver.get(url)
except TimeoutException:
    pass

#this click method works
search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="articles"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[5]/button')
search_button.click();

#I cannot find/get the href links below to print:
profile_page = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content_"]/td[1]/div[2]/div/a')
profile_page = [home.get_attribute("href") for home in profile_page]
print(profile_page)

#I cannot get it to click the next button to do the same thing on the next page:
next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content_"]/td[1]/div[2]/div/a')
next_button.click();
```

Comment: maybe use less tags in xpath - ie, `'//*[@id="content_"]/td//a'`. OR first check if you can get `'//*[@id="content_"]'`, next try with `'//*[@id="content_"]/td'`, etc. to see which tag makes problem.

Comment: @iFreeSki420 This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB I added my goals in the explanation. Is this what you mean?

Comment: time.sleep(5) seemed to do the trick, let me know if there is a more efficient solution

Comment: I can't load page because it blocks my IP - but often `time.sleep` can resolve problem when page uses JavaScript to load data and code has to wait for elements. Selenium has also own methods to [wait for elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) but often `time.sleep` is easier to rember.